# AtomicReference<ArrayList> difficulties and alternatives

Tags: java, concurrency

So in various programs that I have been writing for fun, I have come across concurrent modification exceptions.

In my naive attempt to solve this problem I used an Atomic instead of some sort of concurrent collection. I am somewhat familiar with why this is causing errors. Essentially the individual elements of the ArrayList are not synchronized and can be modified at whim by different threads.

---

Could someone summarize for me

What errors occur when I try to make an atomic reference to a collection

What is a legitimate use case for an atomic reference to an Array or list

What are some better alternatives for storing instances for a game which can be used by multiple threads

---

Comment: " to a collection on a collection" ? what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing what a ConcurrentModification means...

The most common occurrence for this is when you iterate over a collection and modify it in the loop.

For instance if you do the following

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> l = new LinkedList<>();
        for(int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
            l.add("banana"+i);
        }

        for (String s : l) {
            if("banana10".equals(s)) {
                l.remove(s);
            }
        }
    }
```

...this will give you a ConcurrentModificationException. Note, I have not spawned any threads.

The correct way to do the same is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> l = new LinkedList<>();
    for(int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
        l.add("banana"+i);
    }

    for (Iterator<String> iterator = l.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        String s = iterator.next();
        if("banana10".equals(s)) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Note the use of an iterator to modify the collection whilst you are looping over it.

So, I don't think you have a concurrency issue!

If you want to make your collection Thread safe, you need to look at the semantics of the thread safety. If you want to allow multiple threads to access the same collection, a ConcurrentList would be a good approach. If you want a list reference which is atomically set, as a whole, you can use an Atomic reference.

Comment: I'd suggest adding the defensive copy solution

Comment: ConcurrentList? from which library?

Comment: You can either make your List safe via Collections.synchronizedList() or use a Vector.

Answer (score 4):

Using `AtomicReference` to store an object such as a collection is not enough to make it thread safe. Indeed if the object that you put in the `AtomicReference` is not thread safe like an `ArrayList` for example, using it would still be unsafe if we have multiple threads trying to modify its state concurrently. So the good approach is still to put into your `AtomicReference` an immutable object such that its state cannot be modified by multiple threads anymore. In case of a collection you can for example use the methods of type `Collections.unmodifiable*` such as `Collections.unmodifiableList(List)` for the lists, in order to put into the `AtomicReference` the immutable version of your collection.

If you need thread safe collections, you should have a look to the classes in the package `java.util.concurrent`, you will find Collections natively thread safe. For example, if you mostly read and rarely modify your `List`, you can use the thread safe and efficient list [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

Comment: A list produced by `Collections.unmodifiableList(List)` is not immutable. The wrapped list may still change. For truly immutable lists, use for example guava's `ImmutableList`.

Comment: my usecase is not to share immutable Objects ....